# ArrayAdapter : Custom array adapter for list view with image view keeps loading wrong images

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I have a Custom Array Adapter For a list view that contains an Image View. In the custom adapter class I have an asynctask that Downloads a unique picture from a unique url of each item in the list . The problem is the ImageViews for each item keeps changing pictures continously . Please what is there any problem with getting Images from urls through an AsyncTask in a custom array adapter class .

Help is needed (In any form)

Comment: Code is wanted. Please post some code otherwise no one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look of those libraries that can help you :)
[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
[Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with starting an asynchronously loading things for a ListView (or any other adapter sourced view) is that Views can get reused once they are off the screen. The easiest way to deal with this is to use a library to do it for you, my favorite is [AQuery](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/)

If you don't want to go that route, you'll have to role your own. To do this, you will need to check if the view at the completion of the AsyncTask is showing the same stuff as when it started. Call `setTag(tag)` on the View you're returning in the adapter's `getView()`. Then before you set the image to the ImageView, call `getTag()` on the view and check it equals the same object as what you set it as. It should look something like this:

```
final View view = MY VIEW;
final Object tag = new Object();
view.setTag(tag);
new AsyncTask() {
     ...
     public void onPostExecute(Bitmap bar) {
          if(tag.equals(view.getTag()) {
               imageView.setImage(bar);
          }
     }
     ...
}.execute();

return view;
```

And then you can start caching and things like that. Complex right? So yeah, you should use a library.

Comment: Really Complicated ! Thanks for the answer and Insight